# Consider numbers of the form α=a1a2a3…an, with n digits, each digit from the set {1,2,3,4,5,6}.

Tags: combinatorics

Consider numbers of the form $α=a_1a_2a_3…a_n$, with $n$ digits, each digit from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. For example, if $n=4$, the number $α=a_1a_2a_3a_4$ will have 4 digits from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.
Let n=13.

1. How many such numbers are there?

   $6^{13}$
2. How many such numbers are there for which the sum of the digits is even?

   $6^{12}\cdot2$
3. How many such numbers contain more even digits than odd digits?
   $C(13,7)2^72^6 + C(13,8)2^82^5 + C(13,9)2^92^4 + C(13,10)2^{10}2^3 + C(13,11)2^{11}2^2 + C(13,12)2^{12}2 + C(13,13)2^{13}$

Not sure if this is the correct way to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Are you sure about your answer to question 2? Because I'd have thought half the numbers would have even digit sum.

Comment: Not sure to be honest.. My thought is that you can basically add up all the digits, and if the sum is odd number, then you just add an odd number for the last digit, and if the sum is even number, then you just add an even number to make the sum of all digits even, hence the $\cdot2$ at the end

Comment: There are 3 choices each for even digits and odd digits, so you should have $6^{12}\times 3$ for question two. As for question three: If such a number does not contain more even digits than odd digits, then it must contain more odd digits than even digits. There are as many of the former as there are of the latter.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much for such detailed explanations!

Comment: @spin If you got it, can you explain why there must there be an equal number of each type (more odd or more even), esp with the condition that the sum is even? (I can come up with such a reasoning, but I don't think Daniel's claim is a "detailed explanation".)